# Add numbers within mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that I'm using to rank football teams. Basically, every time you click on the picture of a football team, the data is input into a mysql database. I have a column for the number of times the football team has been selected. How do I add 1 to the number in that column every time the football team is clicked, from within the php. Right now I am using an UPDATE command, but I can't get it to work. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 10):

```
 UPDATE click_table SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE team = <team>;
```